# How to convert dd/mm/yyyy to epoch time in Perl?

Tags: perl, time, perl-module, epoch

I have searched several hours for a formula to convert dd/mm/yyyy format into epoch time but have not found a solution.

I have two dates, after converting from 2 different formats, that are now like this "08011985" and "09302014". I have to convert them to epoch time to get the difference from earliest and latest date, and do something based on the size of the spread.

I can't install any modules and am on 5.8.8.

Comment: There are many ways to deal with seeming to not be able to install modules.  Perhaps you should post your circumstances as a question and see if you get a good answer.  Your life with Perl will be MUCH more pleasant.

Comment: I thought "How to convert dd/mm/yyyy to epoch time in Perl?" was concise? I have spent several hours, copying examples, etc with no luck!

Comment: I am suggesting you look into fixing that "I can't install any modules" problem.

Comment: @Schwern if it's anything like my situation, it's a policy problem, not a technical one :)

Comment: @NickP We have solutions to those, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using the [`Time::Local`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Local) module, which has always been a core component of Perl 5.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Local qw/ timelocal /;

for my $date ( qw/ 08011985 09302014 / ) {
  print epoch_for_mmddyyyy($date), "\n";
}

sub epoch_for_mmddyyyy {
  my ($m, $d, $y) = unpack 'A2A2A4', shift;
  timelocal(0, 0, 0, $d, $m-1, $y);
}
```

**output**

```
491698800
1412031600
```

Comment: Since you've chosen my answer as a solution, I've modified it to provide the functionality that you need in a subroutine.

Answer (score 5):

The built-in module [Time::Local](http://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Local) provides the inverse of localtime and gmtime, timelocal and timegm.  They take dates and times and return epoch time.

[perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-take-a-string-and-turn-it-into-epoch-seconds?) covers these sorts of questions.

Comment: I tried this just now from perlfaq4:

`$time = timelocal( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year );

print "time = " . $time . "\n";`

...and I get this error

"Day '' out of range 1..31" and the line number of my script where the code lives.

Comment: Note that months are counted from `0` to `11` for Jan through Dec. That may be your problem.

Comment: @dbonneville, Did you actually provide a valid value for `$mday`? Comments are not the proper place to ask new questions.

Comment: @ikegami, my $mday value was 0 when it needs to be at least a 1. That part is now solved. Thanks!